# Texture gets messed up when appending to blender model

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, blender, modeling, texture-mapping

My problem is, that when I import a model from blender to unity and then apply texture to it, the texture gets completly messed up on the y-axis. Does anybody know how to fix this?

This is in Unity 2018.1

[[image: Messed up texture]

Comment: Looks like bad uv's to me. Assuming it looks good in blender I would check if you have two uv maps on the model, maybe blender is using a [different uvmap](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv/layout_management.html) than unity.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the model in Blender and what the UVs look like?

Comment: The problem is that, as you said, the uvmap is completely messed up. Here is the screenshot: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oyrHhIdzoPzbiBYmRyoaf65cYcMvT70N

Comment: How do I fix the map?